# App for managing calendar menu, cooking, storage, and shopping list making, integrated with Google keep via sharing and importing

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cooking

I am looking for an app that lets me do a meal plan, perhaps, even a rotating one, where, meals, can be defined, for one or more days (with specific meals on specific days).

Next to a planned meal, the user can also edit an actual meal (for instance, the user, may plan a meal calendar, as wished, but, after taking to their spouse, the meal may change (for better, or for worse, doesn't matter). There may also be dietary changes according to the user's health (which, may even change, with time (also as the users go to different doctor appointments, and changes to vitamins and diet are made)).

There may be even the need to schedule different meals for different users (so, there may be different first plates, second plates, and desserts, in different quantities, according to how many users eat each dish (which means the ingredient quantities may change accordingly, but you may have more stuff stocked up).

The user can thus connect the meal plan pages with food stock pages and shopping list pages.

And recipe pages may be imported from Google keep. In Google keep the recipes and pictures of food are kept under a special recipes label, from which some smart ai can read the recipe and guess quantities of ingredients as needed.

When the user goes shopping, they can choose for how many days they want to shop, or what they want to buy, considering how much time it may take for certain ingredients to go bad, and also the quantity in store, which may be programmed (in other words, you can program drawers, shelves, and fridge).

The shopping list can be exported to Google keep, and carried with the phone to the supermarket.

Where can I find such an app?

Thanks.